# Is this a valid proof of $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)^{g(x)}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to show that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)^{g(x)}} = \lim_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)}^{\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{g(x)}}$$ provided $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous functions on the open interval around a.

So I went about saying that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)}^{g(x)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)}\times \lim_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)}\times ... = (\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)})^{g(x)}$$
But what about the limit of $g(x)$?
Thanks

Comment: No, I don't think that would be accepted as a proof anywhere.

Comment: You don't technically need that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous, all you need is that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)$ exist.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD I am asking about the right way to do this.

Comment: If $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ can you really write $f(x)^{g(x)}=f(x)\times f(x)\cdots $? That is wrong. And you did not ask the right way to do this, but rather whether your way was right. Read your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try taking logs. Since log and exp  continuous, the result for the log case is enough.
$$
\lim \limits_{x \to a} g(x) \log f(x).
$$
We can take limits through products. This is a basic result and through logs since they are continuous. The result follows.